# Hibernate + JPA: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I write an educational project. It's a simple chat. Stack of the backend technology is Java, Jetty (server, websocket), Hibernate, PostgreSQL. There is some annotation problem with two dependent entities. The first entity is

```
@Table(name = "users") //public class UsersDataSet
......
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "userIdSequence", sequenceName = "user_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "userIdSequence")
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private long id;

@OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_one")
private ConversationDataSet userOneConversationDataSet;

@OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_two")
private ConversationDataSet userTwoConversationDataSet;

public UsersDataSet() {
}
//getters, setters...
```

The second is

```
@Table(name = "conversation") //public class ConversationDataSet
......
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "cIdSequence", sequenceName = "c_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cIdSequence")
@Column(name = "c_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private long cId;

@Column(name = "user_one", nullable = false)
private long userOne;

@Column(name = "user_two", nullable = false)
private long userTwo;

@OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "userOneConversationDataSet")
private UsersDataSet userOneDataSet;

@OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "userTwoConversationDataSet")
private UsersDataSet userTwoDataSet;

public ConversationDataSet(){

}

public ConversationDataSet(long userOne, long userTwo){
    this.userOne = userOne;
    this.userTwo = userTwo;
}
//getters, setters...
```

The SQL shema is

```
create table users
(
    user_id bigint not null primary key
);
create sequence user_id_sequence start with 1 increment by 1 no cycle owned by users.user_id;

create table conversation
(
    c_id bigint not null primary key,
    user_one bigint not null,
    user_two bigint not null,
    constraint fk_user_one foreign key (user_one) references users(user_id),
    constraint fk_user_two foreign key (user_two) references users(user_id)
);
create sequence c_id_sequence start with 1 increment by 1 no cycle owned by conversation.c_id;
```

When I try to save a new ConversationDataSet object ("conversation") in a database like this `session.save(new ConversationDataSet(userOne, userTwo))`, I get a folowing error

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : dbService.dataSets.ConversationDataSet.userOneDataSet
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:108)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:56)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:115)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:124)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:289)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:250)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:367)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:200)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:143)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:709)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:696)
at dbService.dao.ConversationDAO.save(ConversationDAO.java:46)
at dbService.DBServiceImpl.setConversation(DBServiceImpl.java:82)
at servlets.UsersServlet.doPut(UsersServlet.java:78)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I will be grateful for the help with the problem. Thank you.

Comment: With a bi-directional relationship - which you have here - both sides of the relationship must be set. This error is commonly seen when this is not the case. Ensure then that back reference from user to conversation is set correctly. You can do this in your constructor call. `userOne.setUserOneConversationDataSet(this);` and the same for userTwo.

Comment: Alan, it's interesting. Thank you. I'll try it. I was also visited by this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userOneDataSet` and `userTwoDataSet` both have `optional = false` on their annotations.  This is equivalent to NOT NULL.  You are trying to save an instance that has those two properties as null.

Comment: Taylor, thank you for the answer. It looks like true. I'll try to set userOneDataSet before saving ConversationDataSet object.

Comment: @AlexanderSuvorov FYI, I had `userOneDataSet` in there twice, you have the same thing on `userTwoDataSet` as well

Comment: Taylor, your post was ok. I understood that you meant. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help.